# chrome 119 mobile emulator does not have border (looks strange)

Tags: google-workspace

I updated chrome to 119.0 and now mobile emulator looks floating (previously it had a border which was very convenient)
I am working on windows, but my coworker experiences the same on Linux after the update.
I tried restarting, I looked through the existing questions, I looked through the settings and I can't seem to be able to figure out how to see that border.
Is there a way to fix it?
Thank you very much.
Kira
[Here is the illustration of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0R26.png)